# Interpreting variations in LOCal timer interrupts number

Tags: linux, cpu, interrupt, events

Running a given workload in different CPU isolation (IRQs & processes) configurations, I do not observe significant differences among values (grand total) reported in `/proc/interrupts` & `/proc/stats` apart from the number of Local Timer Interrupts which I find varying by around 20%.

A. From what I knew, when current_clocksource = hpet, local timer interrupts are generated by comparators that will fire an interrupt following an = comparison (and not a >=)
This having the consequence under heavy load to "forget" firing interrupts because current time has gone greater than the targeted value.
From this, I would conclude that, for a given workload, the more LOCs the better. (less dropped events)

B. From what I knew, the system can "coalesce" events and fire a single interrupt for several events that should occur within a timerslack_ns period of time.
From this, I would conclude that, for a given workload and a given timerslack_ns, the less LOCs the better. (More opportunities offered to the system to coalesce)

1. Is my knowledge outdated or not appropriately used? (running under linux 5.4)
2. How can I determine the number of "forgotten" timer events ?
3. How can I determine the number of "coalesced" timer events?
4. Finally, given an identical workload and ignoring power consumption considerations, with only latency & throughput considerations (yes I am aware this is somehow contradictory, this being the reason for my CPU isolation testings) what configuration should I prefer between one offering high numbers (grand total) of LOCs interrupts and one offering much less?
5. In the same context, I have tried disabling `kernel.timer_migration` but failed to notice any significant change. I presume this is evidence that my IRQs & tasks are appropriately marshaled (no need for timer migration => no thread migration) but I could well be wrong and not read the correct set of data.

Comment: What do you mean that local timers are "comparators"? Can you elaborate on how do you thing it works? Because I'm not sure your perception of what "local timers" are is clear to me.

Comment: @aviro : Sorry. I forgot mentioning that, for my benchmarks, current_clocksource = hpet. And believes that with this particular clock source, interrupt generation is handled by comparators. https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/timers/hpet.html